# using two variables (separately) with hyphen between in a $_GET

Tags: php

Having some trouble and I can't figure this one out. I'll just paste what I am trying to do:

Here is my link + the code that handles the link:

```
echo "<a href='/blog/$row[id]/$post_title'>";echo $row['post_title']; echo '</a>';

if (isset($_GET['post_id']) && isset($_GET['title'])) {
    $get_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if (!$get_id) {
            echo 'Post not found.';
            exit();
        }
```

and I have this rewrite_rule

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?post_id=$1&post_title=$2 [L]
```

so if I go to:

```
www.example.com/1/blog-post-title
```

it will bring up the blog post with that id and title. That version works fine with no issues.

But I need to implement a hyphen instead of a slash in the link (after the id), and this is what I tried:

```
echo "<a href='/blog/$row[id]-$post_title'>";echo $row['post_title']; echo '</a>';
```

But when I go to:

```
www.example.com/1-blog-post-title
```

It does not work, and the variable it is trying to look for when I echo '$_GET['post_id']'; is "1-blog".

What am I doing wrong here? Obviously in my link I am connecting the id to the post title..but what exactly am I doing to cause that?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Your anchor tag points to `/blog/$row[id]-$post_title` but your example URL is `www.example.com/1-blog-post-title`. Shouldn't that be `www.example.com/blog/1-post-title`?

Comment: just a mistake in my copy/paste, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your `RewriteRule` to handle the new pattern. For the first matching group use `[^-]*` to match any characters that are not a hyphen, followed by a hyphen, and then match everything else in the second group.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^-]*)-(.+)$ /index.php?post_id=$1&post_title=$2 [L]
```

See the replacement on [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vA6hN1/1).

Comment: Works perfectly. I actually did change from / to - in the rewrite rule, but I didn't change the pattern for the ID. That did the trick, thank you :)